# How To Repeat Split Method After X Times?

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file which I would like to split using the split method. My current code is:

```
string[] alltext = File.ReadAllText(fullPath).Split(new[] { ',' }, 3);
```

The problem I now have is that I want it to loop through the whole in a way that it always splits the text into three pieces that belong together. If I have a text with:

```
testing, testing,  
buenooo diasssss

testing, testing,  
buenooo diasssss

testing, testing,  
buenooo diasssss
```

(the format here is hard to display, but want to show that they are on different lines, so reading line by line will most likely not be possible)
I want "testing", "testing", "buenooo diasssss" to be dispalyed on my console althought they are on different lines.

If I would do it with lines I would simply loop through each line, but this does not work in this case.

Comment: If the string is a,b,c,d,e what's output you want?

Comment: a,b,c and then d,e,(f) . I need to insert it into my program. Before I would use (var) randomvariable[0],randomvariable[1],randomvariable[3] for it and loop through each line. So, i want all values but always only three to use them like writing them on another file and then the next three and so on.

Comment: Can the "buenooo diasssss" text span multiple lines?

Comment: ```var alltext = x.Split(new[] { ',' }).Distinct().ToList();``` Then you can for loop it without duplicate?

Comment: Do you have _any_ authority on the formatting of inbound data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first remove `"\r\n"`(new line) from the text, `then split` and `select the first three items`.

```
var alltext = File.ReadAllText(fullPath).Replace("\r\n","").Split(',').ToList().Take(3);
foreach(var item in alltext)
     Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Edit**

If you want all three items to be displayed in one line in the console:

```
        int lineNumber = 0;
        var alltext = File.ReadAllText(fullPath).Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "," }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
        alltext.RemoveAll(item => item == "");
        while (lineNumber * 3 < alltext.Count)
        {
            var tempList = alltext.Skip(lineNumber * 3).Take(3).ToList(); ;
            lineNumber++;
            Console.WriteLine("line {0} => {1}, {2}, {3}",lineNumber, tempList[0], tempList[1], tempList[2]);
        }
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data =
    File.ReadLines(fullpath)
        .Select((x, n) => (line: x, group: n / 3))
        .GroupBy(x => x.group, x => x.line)
        .Select(x =>
            String
                .Concat(x)
                .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Trim()));
```

That gives me:

[image: data]

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. How would you write each group, one by one, to the console, using 'Console.WriteLine()'?

Comment: @tsfdfT76 - Something like this: `foreach (var g in data) Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" + ", g));`